# Python thread extremely slow

Tags: python, gtk, multiprocessing, pygtk

I am a newbie in python programming.
I started a project for a score-table. The concecpt is very easy. 2 Players, there scores should be raised and a timer that increases. No problem so far.
In addition the whole thing should be controlled by a Wii remote controller.
I started to implement the wii-connection code using threading. If I now execute the code and connect the wii controller the execution becomes more than slow and output comes only sporadically.
The strange thing is, if I now attach strace to that process it runs normal, if it's killed it's slow again and so on.
Did anyone saw that kind of behavior ?
After that I tried to implement the wii connection using multiprocessing.
That worked normal so far, but now I got the problem that I cannot call other windows (gtk) because of the 2 processes that access the same handlers for connecting to the X-server.
What can I do to get this running ?
Many thanks in advance,
best regards,

Nico

main.py should be started to call WiiRemote.py. After succesfull connection WiiWindow.py should be called from main.py to close the window and open the next one.

**main.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

try:
  pygtk.require('2.0')
except:
  pass

import gobject
from Tafel import Tafel
from Wahl  import Wahl
from WiiWindow import WiiWindow
from WiiRemote import WiiRemote
#from thread import start_new_thread
#import threading

class Main:
  def __init__(self):
    self.Tafel = Tafel()
    self.WiiWindow = WiiWindow()
    self.Wahl = Wahl("","")
    self.Wii = WiiRemote(self.callbackWii, self.wiiConnected)
    gobject.timeout_add(1, self.Wii.keepRunning)
    self.currentScreen = 0
    self.showWii()

  def showTafel(self):
    self.currentScreen = 2
    self.Tafel.show()
    self.Tafel.run()

  def showWahl(self):
    self.currentScreen = 1
    gobject.timeout_add(500, self.Wii.keepRunning)
    self.Wahl.show()
    #self.Wahl.run()

  def showWii(self):
    self.currentScreen = 0
    self.WiiWindow.show()
    self.WiiWindow.run()

  def wiiConnected(self, isConnected):
    print("isConn: ",isConnected)
    if (isConnected == True):
      self.WiiWindow.Connected()
      self.showWahl()
    else:
      self.wii.destroy()


  def callbackWii(self, btn):
    print ("wiiClicked: ", btn)
    return
    if (self.currentScreen == 1):
      self.Wahl.callbackWii(btn)
    if (self.currentScreen == 2):
      self.Tafel.callbackWii(btn)




main = Main()
```

**WiiRemote.py:**

```
import cwiid
import time
import threading

class WiiRemote(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, callbackClicked, callbackConnected):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.thread = self
    self.thread.setDaemon = True
    self.thread.start()
    self.callback = callbackClicked
    self.connected = callbackConnected
    self.running = True

  def keepRunning(self):
    return True

  def destroy(self):
    self.running = False

  def run(self):

    while True:
      print 'break'
      time.sleep(1)


    self.button_delay = 0.2
    print 'Press 1 + 2 on your Wii Remote now ...'
    time.sleep(1)

    # Connect to the Wii Remote. If it times out
    # then quit.
    try:
      wii=cwiid.Wiimote()
    except RuntimeError:
      print "Error opening wiimote connection"
      self.connected(False)
      quit()
    self.connected(True)
    print 'Wii Remote connected...\n'
    print 'Press some buttons!\n'
    print 'Press PLUS and MINUS together to disconnect and quit.\n'

    wii.rpt_mode = cwiid.RPT_BTN
    while self.running == True:

      buttons = wii.state['buttons']

      # If Plus and Minus buttons pressed
      # together then rumble and quit.
      if (buttons - cwiid.BTN_PLUS - cwiid.BTN_MINUS == 0):
        print '\nClosing connection ...'
        wii.rumble = 1
        time.sleep(1)
        wii.rumble = 0
        exit(wii)

      # Check if other buttons are pressed by
      # doing a bitwise AND of the buttons number
      # and the predefined constant for that button.
      if (buttons - cwiid.BTN_UP == 0):
        self.callback("UP")
        time.sleep(self.button_delay)
```

**WiiWindow.py**

```
try:
  import pygtk
  import gobject
  pygtk.require('2.0')
  import gtk
  import time
except:
  pass

RCCONN = False

class WiiWindow(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file("wahl.glade")
    self.wwindow = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.BUTworc = self.builder.get_object('BUTworc')  

  def run(self):
    print 'start'
    gtk.main()


  def show(self):
    self.wwindow.show()

  def Connected(self):
    self.wwindow.destroy()
```

Comment: Did you remember to call `gobject.threads_init()` at the beginning of your program?